# Strip only exact match substring from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
name                           id
John McNamara                  3498
Jane Adams, M.D.               6725
Nour Abd Almohsen Jr M.D.      0197
Alex Ambrose PhD               3287
Nancy Ann Brown, MPH, PhD      9127
Kathy W.                       4389
Jack Joshua Smith White        6756
MPHJackie Goldman              3294
Mort Evans                     5586
```

I'm looking for a way to strip substrings from a list, without overstripping.
I've tried using `lstrip` but passing in a list with things like MD, MPH, etc results in single letters being stripped from names that don't contain those substrings (i.e. Mort Evans becomes ort Evans). Using `.replace` has also failed since it doesn't recognize the substrings that are accidentally concatted onto names (i.e. MPHJackie Goldman persists).

Ideally I'd like output that looks like this:

```
name                           id
John McNamara                  3498
Jane Adams                     6725
Nour Abd Almohsen Jr.          0197
Alex Ambrose PhD               3287
Nancy Ann Brown                9127
Kathy W.                       4389
Jack Joshua Smith White        6756
Jackie Goldman                 3294
Mort Evans                     5586
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one that should one match ones at the end. IT could could be better but i created a regex101 that you can test with:

```
r'(M\.D\.,? ?$)|(PhD,? ?$)|(MPH,? ?)|(,)'
```

This site has all of your matches and the regex and what it matches:

https://regex101.com/r/nyaAqJ/3

Here is an apply that works with stripping since strip seems to have a strange behaviour:

```
import re
df['name'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'(?:=M\.D\.,? ?$)|(PhD,? ?$)|(MPH,? ?)|(,)', '', x))
```

and if that works:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'(?:=M\.D\.,? ?$)|(PhD,? ?$)|(MPH,? ?)|(,)', '', x))
```

I hope this helps, if you need any updates, or find use cases where it doesn't work, let me know

Comment: The regex101 doesn't show the leading MPH being captured by this. Also when I try to run this I get a syntax error `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`

Comment: @LMGagne what command are you running, also check out the updated regex site, it has a /2 at the end. Regex let's you update and add, so you can add lines you want, hit update regex and get a new version to share

Comment: @LMGagne, also, on the bottom, there is a tab called substitution, click on that, that will show you what it will look like after substituting, which looks like you data. The window will row up when you click on substitution on the bottom of the regex data window

Comment: It seems like `df['name'].str.strip(r'(M\.D\.,? ?$)|(PhD,? ?$)|(MPH,? ?)')` is actually stripping out leading `M` characters. the regex101 doesn't show this, but when I run the code on my df that's what happens.

Comment: @LMGagne that is so odd, when i do df['name'].str.contains(r'(M\.D\.,? ?$)|(PhD,? ?$)|(MPH,? ?)')  it shows the last line as False. I'm looking into it

Comment: @LMGagne try my latest update in the answer. for some reason strip does not work right on the regext but the regex library does. Let me know what you think.